# heroku cli reports The system cannot find the path specified on Win 10

Tags: heroku-cli

I'm having a problem with the Heroku CLI.

I was following the Heroku tutorial for Node.js.

I installed the Heroku CLI and checked that node --version, npm --version and git --version were at the latest version available.

I then run the command "heroku login" from git bash, but after inserting the email it complained about permissions so I re run git bash in administrator mode and everything seemed fine, I got to the part where you do "heroku create" it started downloading something but then I had a warning about not using git bash for "create" but to opt for powershell or cmd.

So I switched to cmd.exe with admin privileges but now the "heroku" command does nothing:
"$ heroku
The system cannot find the path specified."

The error seems related to my os, I checked my Windows Environment Variables and the path to heroku's exe is correctly set up (in fact it worked a bit earlier) to "C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin".

So I don't know how to use heroku at this point or what can I do to fix this error.

Comment: I've got exactlythe same problem going on. Heroku failed after it automatically pulled some updates and stopped working.

Comment: I unstalled and reinstalled Heroku CLI. It went through the update cycle again which seems to have been succesful this time.

Comment: same thing happened to me @Sigge